# "Client Error" message when trying to implement an Rest API View

Tags: rest, api, drupal, drupal-8

I'm creating an API with Drupal to serve a angular application. The problem is, when I create the view with Rest export and try to access it (via browser or postman), it gaves me an "Client error" message (and nothing more).

I'm using drupal-8.7.6, running with PHP7.3, mysql and apache 2. But I've tried at nginx also and the error appeared again.

To reproduce it, just add some contents, enable the Restful web services, jsonm hal and create a view that exports rest data.

I expect to access the information via GET request (using browser, postman or any other way)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Go to the rest exports view, click on format setting and click accepted request format to json.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your **View**
2. Go to **Format**
3. Click on **Settings** beside **Serializer**
4. Finally check Json option and save.

You are done :)

Comment: after searching for hours you saved me, thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

find out what was happening

I was not specificating the format of output, so Drupal was searching for an html to serve. To workaround this, just add to url: ?_format=json, for example, if my view route is "/articles", it will be: http://drupal.dev/articles?_format=json